# How can i find find a table with a specific name in a SQL linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

Hoping somebody can help, i have this linked server, i need to find certain tables, i can't seem to find them but i know they are there, is there any query i can run to find the name?

Something similar to this?

```
select * 
from sys.tables 
where name like '%database%',
```

this works for tables in the normal DB.

Comment: `..from servername.databasename.sys.tables where name like '%tablename%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the complete path to yout database in the following format:

```
SELECT * FROM [LinkedServer].[DatabaseName].sys.tables where name like '%database%'
```

Comment: I get this error: Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ACKMMSQA". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.

Comment: Not enough permissions for user that is being used for linked server connections.

Comment: @DirkScheepers like the comment above says, this is a permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the help!

Comment: @DirkScheepers Happy to help. If this asnwer helped, accepting it as correct would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from linked_server_name.db_name.sys.tables 
where name like '%database%',
```